# How can I create a list of new objects in C#?

Tags: c#, list, object

I'd like to create a list of objects for a list. I understand it possible to do this below but this isn't what I am after.

```
view.BindingContext =
                new ViewModel
            { 
                List = new List<Section> {
                    new Section
                    {
                        Title = "Chapter 1",
                        List = new List<Reading> {
                            new Reading { Title = "Title" Text = "abc" },
                            new Reading { Title = "Title" Text = "abc" },
                            new Reading { Title = "Title" Text = "abc" },
                            new Reading { Title = "Title" Text = "abc" },
                            new Reading { Title = "Title" Text = "abc" },
                            new Reading { Title = "Title" Text = "abc" },
                            new Reading { Title = "Title" Text = "abc" },
                        }
                    },
                }
            };
```

Instead of the code above I'd like to create new objects from another list of objects. so something like this;

```
view.BindingContext =
            new ViewModel
            {
                List = new List<Section>
                {
                 foreach(Chapter chapter in ChapterList)
                    {
                    new Section { Title = chapter.Title, List = chapter.ReadingList },
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: Use the .AddRange() Method on a List and put the new List as parameter.

Comment: A linq statement could replace the foreach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could just loop *after* the initial construction. Doing everything in one statement is over-rated.

However!

```
new List<Foo>(oldList.Select(x => new Foo { A = x.A, B = x.B, ... }))
```

should work as a simple clone of the list and list items, as would:

```
oldList.ConvertAll(x => new Foo { A = x.A, B = x.B, ...})
```

or (as noted in the comments)

```
oldList.Select(x => new Foo { A = x.A, B = x.B, ... }).ToList()
```

Comment: Why not `oldList.Select(x => new Foo { ... }).ToList()`?

Comment: @ZevSpitz tom-ay-toes tom-ah-toes; indeed, either will work

Comment: True, although I personally think `oldList.Select(...).ToList()` more clearly expresses the flow of the data from left to right, than `new List<Foo>(oldList.Select(...))` -- think `toes(tom-ay)` vs `tom-ay-toes`.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks Marc, very helpful. Ended up using 
'new List<Foo>(oldList.Select(x => new Foo { A = x.A, B = x.B, ... }))'

Answer (score -1):

You could make a whole new list of the new object type you need to have list of. 
And for each item in chapterlist, you could create a new list element and add it to the newly made list. So you could serialize or create an object for the each list element.

```
new ViewModel
        { 
            Newlist List<differentlist> = new List<differentlist>();

            List = new List<Section> {
                new Section
                {
                    var ChapterList = new List<ChapterList>(); 
                    foreach(var Chapter in ChapterList ){
                        differentlist new = {Title = String.Empty, List = String.Empty};
                        new.Title = Chapter.Title;
                        new.List = Chapter.list;
                        Newlist.Add(new);
                    };
              }
         }
```

Comment: Will this compile? Can you use `var` and `foreach` statements within an object initializer this way?

Comment: @ZevSpitz no, no it won't.